# No such file or directory : while running hashicorp packer docker image through octopus deploy

Tags: docker, octopus-deploy

I am using Hashicorp packer official docker image to validate and create a custom AMI. Below is the command I am using to validate the template2.json file which has the code to create custom AMI. I am using octopus deploy worker pool to execute this command.

docker run -i ee26c209af37 validate template2.json

but it's not able to detect the template2.json file and  is giving "No such file or directory". Can you please advise if you guys have faced this kind of scenario.I have tried giving full path before template2.json also but same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file `template2.json` is not visible from the container. You would typically mount the file into your container, roughly as follows:

```
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd),target=/mnt/packer -w /mnt/packer hashicorp/packer:latest validate template2.json
```

See the [official documentation of the docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/packer).